# Visual software system monitor

Tags: user-interface, system, monitor

anyone ever see the visual monitoring tools factories and plants have? they show components of the manufacturing system in something reminiscent of a flowchart or visio diagram, but instead of a static image, each component has some interactive element (e.g. showing system stats or messages)

I want to build something like this for an all-software system. are there any tools or components I can use to build the gui? is there a name for this type of tool? I can't figure out the right query to find sample images on google.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I've seen to something like this is the [Microsoft Visual Studio Analyzer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728806(VS.71).aspx); it can monitor hardware and software components and graphically show the communication between them.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are seeking instrument gauges and graphics.

there are some free controls and some expensive controls and a ton in between.

Here are a few examples;

http://www.cstsoft.com/english/index.html

http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Programming/Components_and_Libraries/Nextwave_Software_WPF_Suite_with_Chart_and_Gauge_Screenshot.html

http://www.dundas.com/index.aspx?Campaign=GoogleGauge&gclid=CNXn7rmL2pgCFR2dnAodyl2HdA

http://www.freedownloadscenter.com/Best/free-gauge-_net.html

and this certainly is not an all inclusive list -- Google yields many more and your choice of development environment --

hope it helps.